# XMLHttpRequest: Как возобновить закачку

Tags: javascript, html5, xmlhttprequest

Тут я пытался что то навалять примерно так:

```
var slice = file.slice(10, 100); // прочитать байты с 10 го по 99 й 

xhr.send(slice); //и отправить эти байты в запросе.
```

Но такая модель не жизнеспособна!

Как отослать на сервер не весь файл, а только нужную часть его?

Или поставить на паузу закачку а потом либо отменить либо продолжить.

С помощью javascript как можно это сделать?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для загрузки нам нужно точно знать количество загруженных байт. Это может сообщить только сервер.

**Алгоритм возобновляемой загрузки**

Загрузкой файла будет заведовать объект Uploader, его примерный общий вид:

```
function Uploader(file, onSuccess, onFail, onProgress) {

  // fileId уникальным образом идентифицирует файл
  // можно добавить идентификатор сессии посетителя, но он и так будет в заголовках
  var fileId = file.name + '-' + file.size + '-' + +file.lastModifiedDate;

  // сделать из fileId число (хеш, алгоритм неважен), мы будем передавать его в заголовке,
  // в заголовках разрешены только ASCII-символы
  fileId = hashCode(fileId);

  var errorCount = 0;

  // если количество ошибок подряд превысит MAX_ERROR_COUNT, то стоп
  var MAX_ERROR_COUNT = 6;

  var startByte = 0;

  var xhrUpload;
  var xhrStatus;

  function upload() {
    console.log("upload: check status");
    xhrStatus = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhrStatus.onload = xhrStatus.onerror = function() {

      if (this.status == 200) {
        startByte = +this.responseText || 0;
        console.log("upload: startByte=" + startByte);
        send();
        return;
      }

      // что-то не так
      if (errorCount++ < MAX_ERROR_COUNT) {
        setTimeout(upload, 1000 * errorCount); // через 1 сек пробуем ещё раз
      } else {
        onError(this.statusText);
      }

    };

    xhrStatus.open("GET", "status", true);
    xhrStatus.setRequestHeader('X-File-Id', fileId);
    xhrStatus.send();
  }


  function send() {

    xhrUpload = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhrUpload.onload = xhrUpload.onerror = function() {
      console.log("upload end status:" + this.status + " text:" + this.statusText);

      if (this.status == 200) {
        // успешное завершение загрузки
        onSuccess();
        return;
      }

      // что-то не так
      if (errorCount++ < MAX_ERROR_COUNT) {
        setTimeout(resume, 1000 * errorCount); // через 1,2,4,8,16 сек пробуем ещё раз
      } else {
        onError(this.statusText);
      }
    };

    xhrUpload.open("POST", "upload", true);
    // какой файл догружаем /загружаем
    xhrUpload.setRequestHeader('X-File-Id', fileId);

    xhrUpload.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
      errorCount = 0;
      onProgress(startByte + e.loaded, startByte + e.total);
    }

    // отослать, начиная с байта startByte
    xhrUpload.send(file.slice(startByte));
  }

  function pause() {
    xhrStatus && xhrStatus.abort();
    xhrUpload && xhrUpload.abort();
  }


  this.upload = upload;
  this.pause = pause;
}

// вспомогательная функция: получение 32-битного числа из строки

function hashCode(str) {
  if (str.length == 0) return 0;

  var hash = 0,
    i, chr, len;
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    chr = str.charCodeAt(i);
    hash = ((hash << 5) - hash) + chr;
    hash |= 0; // Convert to 32bit integer
  }
  return hash;
};
```

1. Аргументы для new Uploader:

**file**

Объект File API. Может быть получен из формы, либо как результат Drag’n’Drop.
onSuccess, onFail, onProgress
Функции-коллбэки, которые будут вызываться в процессе (`onProgress`) и при окончании загрузки.
Подробнее про важные данные, с которыми мы будем работать в процессе загрузки:

**fileId**

Уникальный идентификатор файла, генерируется по имени, размеру и дате модификации. По нему мы всегда сможем возобновить загрузку, в том числе и после закрытия и открытия браузера.

**startByte**

С какого байта загружать. Изначально – с нулевого.

**errorCount / MAX_ERROR_COUNT**

Текущее число ошибок / максимальное число ошибок подряд, после которого загрузка считается проваленной.
Алгоритм загрузки:

1. Генерируем fileId из названия, размера, даты модификации файла.
   Можно добавить и идентификатор посетителя.
2. Спрашиваем сервер, есть ли уже такой файл, и если да – сколько байт
   уже загружено?
3. Отсылаем файл с позиции, которую сказал сервер. При этом загрузку
   можно прервать в любой момент, просто оборвав все запросы.

**[Вы можете скачать пример и запустить локально для полноценной демонстрации:](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-resume)**

Comment: Спасибо большое,прямо в точку :)

Comment: А вы принципиально отвечаете только на вопросы этого пользователя?

Answer (score 2):

**Отправка файла по частям**

API файлов существенно облегчает отправку больших файлов. Методика такова: крупный файл разбивается на несколько мелких, которые затем отправляются с помощью XHR и собираются обратно на сервере. Примерно так же Gmail быстро отправляет большие прикрепленные файлы. Эта технология также позволяет обойти ограничение Google App Engine: 32 МБ на один HTTP-запрос.

```
window.BlobBuilder = window.MozBlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder ||
                     window.BlobBuilder;

function upload(blobOrFile) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '/server', true);
  xhr.onload = function(e) { ... };
  xhr.send(blobOrFile);
}

document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var blob = this.files[0];

  const BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 1024 * 1024; // 1MB chunk sizes.
  const SIZE = blob.size;

  var start = 0;
  var end = BYTES_PER_CHUNK;

  while(start < SIZE) {

    // Note: blob.slice has changed semantics and been prefixed. See http://goo.gl/U9mE5.
    if ('mozSlice' in blob) {
      var chunk = blob.mozSlice(start, end);
    } else {
      var chunk = blob.webkitSlice(start, end);
    }

    upload(chunk);

    start = end;
    end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
  }
}, false);

})();
```

[Источник](http://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/file/xhr2/)

Comment: С помощью вашего примера сложно будет поставить паузу.Сперва надо остановить цикл,который по моему невозможно.а потом при возобновлении понять на которой итрации остановились и сколько байтов было отправлено.Сложновато нe так ли ?

Comment: Согласен, ваш пример в этом вопросе подходит более чем мой.

Comment: Все равно спасибо Dmitry Petukhov. интересный подход тоже.можно что то из этого полезного извлечь